# React - hook with shared state for different components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 components and a hook. I want those components to share the same state through the hook.
I created this simple codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-resonance-inxbcz?file=/src/hook.js , (when you click a button it adds an item to an array), but as I see those components have separate states. Is there a simple way to use one state for all of those components?
UP: In my live app, those components are far away from each other, on different pages.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share you should use useState instead of useRef as useRef dont trigger component updates.

On the other hand here is an example of what i think you are trying to achieve:

```
export default function App() {
  const UseCustomHook = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return [count, setCount];
  };

  const [counter, setCounter] = UseCustomHook();

  const ComponentOne = ({ setCount, count }) => (
    <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>
      Compo 1 {count}
    </button>
  );
  const ComponentTwo = ({ setCount, count }) => (
    <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>
      Compo 2 {count}
    </button>
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentOne count={counter} setCount={setCounter} />
      <ComponentTwo count={counter} setCount={setCounter} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

if you need to share states trhough your app components on different levels then you should switch to useContext https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext